# Creating multiple tar files in batches duration increases with every batch

Tags: php

I've written a script to get all image records from a database, use each image's tempname to find the imagine on disk, copy it to a new folder and create a tar file out of these files. To do so, I'm using PHP's [PharData](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php). The problem is the images being TIFF files, and pretty large ones at that (the entire folder of 2000-ish images is 95gb in size).

Initially I created one archive, looped through all database records to find the specific file and used `PharData::addFile()` to add each file to the archive individually, but this eventually lead to adding a single file taking 15+ seconds.

I've now switched to using `PharData::buildFromDirectory` in batches, which is significantly faster, but the time to create batches increases with each batch. The first batch got done in 28 seconds, the second in 110, the third one didn't even finish. Code;

```
$imageLocation = '/path/to/imagefolder';
$copyLocation = '/path/to/backupfolder';

$images = [images];

$archive = new PharData($copyLocation . '/images.tar');

// Set timeout to an hour (adding 2000 files to a tar archive takes time apparently), should be enough
set_time_limit(3600);

$time = microtime(true);
$inCurrentBatch = 0;
$perBatch = 100; // Amount of files to be included in one archive file
$archiveNumber = 1;

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $path = $imageLocation . '/' . $image->getTempname();

    // If the file exists, copy to folder with proper file name
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $copyName = $image->getFilename() . '.tiff';
        $copyPath = $copyLocation . '/' . $copyName;
        copy($path, $copyPath);
        $inCurrentBatch++;

        // If the current batch reached the limit, add all files to the archive and remove .tiff files
        if ($inCurrentBatch === $perBatch) {
            $archive = new PharData($copyLocation . "/images_{$archiveNumber}.tar");
            $archive->buildFromDirectory($copyLocation);
            array_map('unlink', glob("{$copyLocation}/*.tiff"));
            $inCurrentBatch = 0;
            $archiveNumber++;
        }
    }
}

// Archive any leftover files in a last archive
if (glob("{$copyLocation}/*.tiff")) {
    $archive = new PharData($copyLocation . "/images_{$archiveNumber}.tar");
    $archive->buildFromDirectory($copyLocation);
    array_map('unlink', glob("{$copyLocation}/*.tiff"));
}

$taken = microtime(true) - $time;
echo "Done in {$taken} seconds\n";
exit(0);
```

The copied images get removed in between batches to save on disk space.

We're fine with the entire script taking a while, but I don't understand why the time to create an archive increases so much in between batch.

Comment: Does `$copyLocation` contain the archives themselves? Wondering if when you `unlink`, you're just removing the `tiff` files but the existing archives will still be present and will be included in the next archive. Try to create your archive in a directory above `$copyLocation`.

Comment: I'm an idiot, that's exactly what's happening. Wondering how I didn't realize, haha

Comment: Sometimes you just need a 2nd pair of eyes. Glad I could help.